# How to instantiate a specific subtype from param array?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

Consider the following code:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    abstract void DoWork();
    virtual void MoreWork() {
        Console.WriteLine("MoreWork");
    }
}
public class classA : BaseClass {
    public void DoWork() { DoStuffA(); }
}
public class classB : BaseClass {
    public void DoWork() { DoStuffB(); }
}
```

I want to have a method to which I'd like to pass all these types and have them be instantiated.

```
void Initialize(params BaseClass[] lst) {
    for (int i = 0; i < objectList.Length; i++) {
       Activator.CreateInstance(objectList[i]); // not sure if this works.
    }
}

Initialize(classA, classB);
```

How do I pull off something like that?

Comment: You cannot use `classA` and `classB` as values; they are types. You can use `Initialize<classA, classB>();` for a generic method, but you cannot create something similar to "`params`" for type parameters. Or you can use `Initialize(typeof(classA), typeof(classB));` as in the answer. Besides that, lots of things in your code don't compile, for example virtual methods (including abstract ones) can't be private, their overrides must declare the same access level and use the `override` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You should not send object instances to the initialize method, but their types.

```
void Initialize(params Type[] lst) {
    foreach(Type type in lst) {
       Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}

Initialize(typeof(classA), typeof(classB));
```

Here is a complete example:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Initialize(typeof(ClassA), typeof(ClassB));
    }

    public class BaseClass { }

    public class ClassA : BaseClass { }

    public class ClassB : BaseClass { }

    public BaseClass[] Initialize(params Type[] lst)
    {
        // if we already know the item count, why not set the capacity of the list.
        List<BaseClass> instances = new List<BaseClass>(lst.Length);

        foreach (Type type in lst)
            if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass)))
                instances.Add((BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type));

        return instances.ToArray();
    }
```